# How to prevent the reset of a form component in React?

Tags: reactjs, forms

I'm a beginner at React, and I'm trying to make a simple app that takes email and password input from a user, and if the user registers the password successfully, it shows a simple "next step" component. But the thing is, it always resets back to the email registration component everytime I submit the password correctly. It shows the "next step" component for a brief second, then it resets. How to prevent this? What am I doing wrong?

Here's the main `App.jsx` file:

```
import Header from './components/Header'
import EmailTaker from './components/EmailTaker'
import PasswordTaker from './components/PasswordTaker'
import NextStep from './components/NextStep'


function GeneralInformationForm(){
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");


  function submitEmailHandler(e) {
    setEmail(e.currentTarget.email.value)
  }

  function submitPasswordHandler(e) {
    setPassword(e.currentTarget.password.value)
  }

  return(
    <>
      {email.length > 0 ?
        <PasswordTaker onSubmit={submitPasswordHandler} />
      : 
        <EmailTaker onSubmit={submitEmailHandler} />
      }
      {password.length > 0 && <NextStep/>}
    </>
  )
}


function App() {

  return (
    <>
      <Header/>
      <GeneralInformationForm/>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Here's the `EmailTaker.jsx` and`PasswordTaker.jsx` files (they are basically almost the same thing):

```
export default function EmailTaker(props) {
    return(
      <div>
        <p>Please enter your email.</p>
        <form onSubmit={props.onSubmit}>
          <label>
            Email:
            <input type='email' name='email' />
          </label>
          <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

The `Header.jsx` and `NextStep.jsx` files are simple HTML stuff I've put on just to test things out.

I've tried to put on different logic to the return part of the GeneralInformationForm function, but it always got even more effed-up the more i messed with it. I've deleted a LOT of unnecessary stuff of the main App.jsx file too, and that's about it.

Comment: Because u forgot to set value into input
`<input type='email' name='email' value={props.value}/>` trying to do something like this with value is email   `<EmailTaker value={email} onSubmit={submitEmailHandler} />`

Comment: @vctqs1 when I do this, it makes the input field inaccessible to changes

Answer (score 0):

Stop page reloading/refreshing:

```js
function submitEmailHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();                   // <----
    setEmail(e.currentTarget.email.value)
  }
```

If doesn't work, pass your email and password as prop and set it to input value respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you're facing is likely due to the fact that your form is being submitted in the default way, causing a page to reload, and thus resetting the state. To prevent this behavior, you should prevent the default form submission.

with this, your page will not reload and the state will be maintained as expected.

```
function submitEmailHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); 
  setEmail(e.currentTarget.email.value);
}

function submitPasswordHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); 
  setPassword(e.currentTarget.password.value);
}
```